# multiply entries with a single add

Tags: cakephp-2.0, repeat

I'm trying to add a repeat function to my Events/add.
So if I have the same Event from Monday to Friday (or even more days) the user can add everything in a single add, instead than one by one.

I added an input field in Events/add.ctp which is:

```
$this->Form->input('repeat', array('type' => 'number'));
```

to compare it in a do - while loop in beforeSave()

```
            if(!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['repeat'])) {
                    $repeat = $this->data['Event']['repeat'];
                    $i = 0;
                    do {
                            $start = strtotime($this->data[$this->alias]['start'] . ' +1 day');
                            $end = strtotime($this->data[$this->alias]['end'] . ' +1 day');
                            $this->data[$this->alias]['start'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
                            $this->data[$this->alias]['end'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end);
                            $this->create();
                            $this->save($this->data);
                            //i think here's the problem... this shouldn't be done here right?

                            $i++;
                    } while ($repeat >= $i);
            }
```

I ran out of ideas on how to make this possible..
I know that I have to use beforeSave to handle data after the add action, but obviously I cannot save data in before save... any hints?

Comment: Wait, the loop works though? Is your question about what's the best recommended place to do that loop, o is the loop simply not working?

Comment: about "the best place to do it", i got also problems in the loop work i'll solve soon, but my question is about creating more entries after an add action. where is the right place to create() and save()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely don't do it in beforeSave. As you said, is kind of weird having a save inside a beforeSave... Hasn't it give you loop problems even? Because you do a save inside the loop, and `$this->data` keeps having the same `repeat` value inside... it will be repeating forever and spaming that poor events table.

No, definitely get that loop out of there.

I think the best way to do this is to add a new function in your model

```
public function saveRepeating($data) {
   if(!empty($data[$this->alias]['repeat'])) {
      $repeat = $data['Event']['repeat'];
      unset($data['Event']['repeat']);   //prevent loops!
      $i = 0;
      do {
         $start = strtotime($data[$this->alias]['start'] . ' +1 day');
         $end = strtotime($data[$this->alias]['end'] . ' +1 day');
         $data[$this->alias]['start'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
         $data[$this->alias]['end'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end);
         $this->create();
         $this->save($data);
         $i++;
     } while ($repeat >= $i);
   }
}
```

And in your controller, call that function instead of save with

```
$this->Model->saveRepeating($data);
```

Notice I didn't really change anything inside your loop, just `$this->data` for `$data`. But having it as a separate function avoids any weird problems with beforeSave. Oh, and I added an unset to the repeat variable to prevent any loop (delete that unset if you want to save the repeat value to a table, though). You can add a return value to validate that every event got saved, or handle exceptions, etc.

Remember to return the beforeSave as it was before!